# Are there any laws in place for a potential lunar territorial dispute?

Tags: the-moon, lunar-base

Considering the limited number of sites of interest to both the [Artemis program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis_program#Artemis_Base_Camp) and the [International Lunar Research Station (ILRS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Lunar_Research_Station), it would seem more than likely that both projects, and by extension the superpowers behind them, would be in a space race to get there before their counterparts. [Due to the lack of current jurisdiction, basically whoever gets there first has the right to operate](https://www.defenseone.com/technology/2021/08/if-china-and-us-claim-same-moon-base-site-who-wins/184352/).

But what's stopping another state from deliberately setting up camp right next to yours? In the Artemis Accords, signatories endorsed the idea of "safety zones" to require communication between parties operating in the same area, but the major players in ILRS (China and Russia) aren't likely to be part of the treaty anytime soon.

Additionally, I wonder what are the legal implications for members of *both* projects (currently only [the](https://laibaamir.medium.com/uae-and-chinas-lunar-research-partnership-a-new-frontier-in-bilateral-ties-7de119ff2910) [UAE](https://www.nasa.gov/news-release/nasa-united-arab-emirates-announce-artemis-lunar-gateway-airlock/))?

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not asking what happens if two entities vie for the same location for their bases (this is a first come first serve basis). I'm asking what are the laws surrounding securing your lunar operations against adversaries that undermine yours.

Comment: The concept of "international laws" is a little wonky to begin with... are you asking what treaties would apply to the situation or what?  There really isn't any way to impose rules on another nation who hasn't agreed to be imposed upon.

Comment: (I mean other than violence or the threat thereof.)

Comment: Season 2 of "For All Mankind" explored this topic. There's also a session at the upcoming  [International Space Development Conference](https://isdc.nss.org/isdc_tracks/space-law-and-policy-2024/) with talks on this topic.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym I doubt any of the current treaties apply here?  Are there any legal ramifications or recourse available, be it through space laws or any other international legislation?

Comment: @phil1008 Interesting, looking forward to the outcomes of the conference. Will be looking to watch the show as well, thank you.

Comment: @ShawnLim That's kinda my point. If twenty nations agree to a list of rules about *anything* and then nation 21 say "forget you guys, I'm doin' my own thing", what exactly can the twenty nations do?  It's either embargo or invade, really. If one nation set up a moon base right next to another nation's moon base, the options are the same as for any international squabble -- blockade their ports to force them to behave, or send troops/cruise missiles/etc.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym It would seem then that the answer to this question would be none. Any potential disputes would be settled either through violence, politicking, or/and making up international laws as they go

Answer (score 1):

In theory, Article II of the [Outer Space Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_Space_Treaty) (signed by all spacefaring powers and most of the rest of the world) prevents territorial disputes by prohibiting claims of sovereignty, while Article IX mandates cooperation and Article XII mandates that any installation on the Moon or another celestial body be open to visits from other parties to the treaty.

In practice, I expect disputes will be resolved in the usual fashion: in favor of whoever is carrying the biggest stick.

Comment: "We don't know nothin bout no SOV URN TEA, but we got 'exclusive rights' to this here lunar watering hole. So why don't you mosey along now"